# Does Spring Cloud Gateway support SOAP or not?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

may I ask if Spring Cloud Gateway supports SOAP or not? If yes is there any special settings?

I have implemented some routes to REST API and it is successful. However when I add more routes for SOAP it is always 404 error. Logs are below:

```
"POST /icomm/OnlineMessageWSService HTTP/1.1" 404 1804 158 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_221)"
```

Comment: Any luck with finding a sample?